# how to find Particle swarm optimization (PSO) fitness function in R programming?

Tags: r, machine-learning, particle-swarm, fitness

I'm new to Machine Learning, so kindly ask for more details if required or do point me towards the resources I should read to have a better understanding. Lets say I have a data set consisting of these columns

`"A" "B" "C" "D" "Target"`

`Target` column is a boolean which I need to predict. My task is to use Particle Swarm Optimization. I know the theory behind PSO, I know it finds the fittest solution out of candidate solutions by using velocity, position, personal best and global best. In R we have a function `pso(func, S = 350, lim_inf, lim_sup, e = 0.0001, data = NULL, N = 500, prop = 0.2)`. The func here is objective function or fitness function. I want to know how do I write a fitness function for my dataset.

Or have I misunderstood `PSO` and it's implementation. Please point me towards any useful resources.

Comment: You may be interested in the hydroPSO package: https://cran.r-project.org/package=hydroPSO